# How to get Google prices on different websites?

Tags: xcode, google-search-api, google-shopping

I'm currently building an app for thrifting clothes, accessories, etc, and I have it set up to use the IPhone's camera to take a picture and google search by image to find the closest match.

What I want to do is get prices from multiple websites, such as Amazon, Ebay, Poshmark, etc, so I can display the lowest to highest prices as a range.

Is there a way to get prices from these websites despite the different layouts?

Im using Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are a single devloper and what you are trying to accomplish is something relativley big.

Depending on your country you should look for a "Price-Comparision-API" like https://funnel.io/. Mining this price data yourself will likely be a daunting task for a single developer.